# Best way to return IDisposable object and only disposing on Exception?

Tags: c#, exception, idisposable

I've been searching for answer on this but I couldn't really find the exact case I'm implementing. I want to return IDisposable object within a method without Disposing/Closing in the same method. But I want to dispose the object only when Exception is raised.  What would be the best way to handle in this case? Following is the current way I'm handling this case.

```
public DisposableObject GetObject()
{
   DisposableObject object = null;

   try
   {
      object = new DisposableObject();
      object.Open();
   }
   catch
   {
      if (object != null)
      {
         object.Close();
      }
      throw;
   }
   return object;
}
```

The object created from above method will be consumed and disposed by other method like this.

```
public void OtherMethod()
{
  using(var object2 = GetObject())
  {
    DoSomethingWithObject2(object2);
  }
}
```

Is there any other option here in this case?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `object.Dispose()` inside the `catch`?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why anyone would want to do this.  Also, looks like removing that `throw` would allow it to return, but the exception wouldn't be handled.

Comment: Can you provide a real world example? This code isn't even valid C#. It might be easier to provide an answer if we knew what you were trying to *accomplish* rather than how you're attempting to implement it.

Comment: This seems very XY-ish. A real-word example would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Morton said, the issue is with calling `Open` on the `DisposableObject` instance within the factory method, but I don't agree with the corrosponding solution.

The *real* problem is that `Open` is a leaky abstraction. Why would I want to instantiate an invalid instance? When I want a file stream, I call `File.Open(...)`, I don't instantiate a new `Stream` and call `OpenFile(...)`. That would force me to know how to open the file, and defeat the purpose of the factory method alltogether (yes, `File.Open` is a factory method for a `Stream` instance).

So when I read a file, I read it like this:

```
using (var stream = File.Open("myFile.text", FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

I don't have to worry about how to close the file if the file couldn't be opened properly. *In fact*, If the `Open` call throws an exception, the `using` statement can't even call `Dispose()` on `stream`, because stream hasn't been assigned yet and execution flow hasn't even entered the `using` statement's block scope yet.

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var obj = MyObj.Create())
            {
                // everything is already in a valid state.
                var message = obj.ReadMessage();

                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If the factory succeeded, the using statement did the cleanup.
            // if the factory failed, the factory took care of the cleanup.
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyObj : IDisposable
{
    public static MyObj Create()
    {
        Stream stream = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            stream = File.Open("myFile.txt", FileMode.Create);
            reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            return new MyObj(reader);
        }
        catch
        {
            reader?.Dispose();
            stream?.Dispose();

            throw;
        }
    }

    private readonly StreamReader _reader;

    private MyObj(StreamReader reader)
    {
        _reader = reader;
    }

    public string ReadMessage()
    {
        return "the message: " + _reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _reader?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd rather push all responsibility of openening and closing the connnection to the user of this object instead of the factory.

The current method you have shown, one cannot create an instance, e.g. testing, without creating the actual connection. Furthermore, is the method not transparent, as another person would not assume the connection to be opened.

The method I've posted enables the user of your code to easier handle the error which may occure from opening the DisposableObject.

```
    public DisposableObject GetObject() {
        return new DisposableObject();
    }

    public void OtherMethod() {
        using (DisposableObject o = GetObject()) {
            try {
                o.Open();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Log(ex);
            } finally {
                // If not called within the dispose function.
                o.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Though, if you would like to handle the opening, your method is alright. However, I would change some minor details:

```
    public DisposableObject GetObject() {
        var o = new DisposableObject();
        try {                
            o.Open();
            return o;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            o.Dispose(); // o.Close is called within.
            throw ex;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: `o` exists in an invalid state, and the factory method is what enables that to be the case. Your solution is an anti-pattern.